# How do you set-up a mongoose column from schema A to have the values from a column from schema B?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have

> schema A:

```
let informationAssetsRow = new Schema({
  infAss: {
    type: String
})
```

> Schema B

```
let informationAssetsSeverityEvaluationRow = new Schema({
  Informationasset: {
    type: String
  }
})
```

For the sake of simplicity I have removed other attributes.
What I would like to do is:
Each time a document inserted in collection A. I want the value of infAss to be also inserted in Informationasset in column B.
From SQL perspective, this seems to be infAss of collection A should be set-up as an external key to schema B. I'm not sure I'm right.
However, in mongodb it's not clear if that is doable.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a post('save') hook on `informationAssetsRow` schema to achieve what you want.

Everytime a new document is inserted in `collection A`, `post` save hook will save new document into `collection B`.

Try this:

```
informationAssetsRow.post('save',function(doc){
    informationAssetsSeverityEvaluationRow.create({
        Informationasset : doc.infAss
    })
})
```

Read more about [Mongoose Post Hooks](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post) for detailed information.